# What approach should be made to successfully use a specific variable?

Tags: protractor

I have a function were in I need to update multiple dropdown lists.

Since I want to remove manual interventions, I want the test to automatically decide which data to be used.

I have 2 sets of array/variable on my main tests.

```
arrDefinition1 = ['Section;Sec1', 'Domain;test1', 'Process layer;test1', 'Skill;test1'];
arrDefinition2 = ['Section;Sec2', 'Domain;test2', 'Process layer;test2', 'Skill;test2'];
```

If the current value of the dropdown list is "**Sec1**" then **arrDefinition2** will be used and vise-versa.

But due to promises, my **IF** condition was executed first before the **IT** and the variable that contains the value of getText contains "**undefined**", which means **arrDefinition2** will always be used.

```
    it('should click the Edit icon of the first row of Activity table', function() {
        waitForElement(5, elmFirstRow, true);
        editFirstRow.click();

        waitForElement(5, element(by.id('section')), true);
        element(by.id('section')).getText().then(function (tmpText) {
            tempObject.strSection = tmpText;
        }); 
    });

    if (tempObject.strSection == 'Sec1') {
        console.log('first');
        fillUpForm(0, tempObject.arrDefinition2, 'UpdateMDef');
    } else {
        console.log('second');
        fillUpForm(0, tempObject.arrDefinition1, 'UpdateMDef');
    }
```

Note: The function fillUpForm consists of **IT** functions.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.